# Vue,js 2.0 -- Errors Incorrect when installing a package

Tags: vue.js

DevTools tells me it has detected Vue 2.1.6

I tried to install a package and received these errors and I am unsure how to continue

> ```
> > npm install vue2-google-maps --save
> > /Users/jgravois/Documents/Code/_work/teamsite53 ├── UNMET PEER
> > DEPENDENCY marker-clusterer-plus@^2.1.4 ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
> > vue@2.0.7 invalid └── vue2-google-maps@0.5.2
> > 
> > npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> > '/Users/jgravois/Documents/Code/_work/teamsite53/node_modules/fobject/package.json'
> > npm WARN vue2-google-maps@0.5.2 requires a peer of vue@^2.1.0 but none
> > was installed. npm WARN vue2-google-maps@0.5.2 requires a peer of
> > marker-clusterer-plus@^2.1.4 but none was installed.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install vue with save `npm install vue --save` 
Try deleting the vue package from `node_modules` and run an `npm install`